# Is it possible to express the entire Tetris game using matrix / linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm wondering if it is possible to express the entire Tetris game using matrix / linear algebra.

For example, at `t0`, my game can be expressed as a matrix `M0`:

```
0 0 0 0 0
0 2 2 0 0
0 0 2 2 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
1 1 0 0 0
```

at the next tick `t1`, the piece will move down by 1 and becomes `M1`:

```
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 2 2 0 0
0 0 2 2 0
0 0 0 0 0
1 1 0 0 0
```

If the player rotates the piece counter-clock-wise at `t2`, we get `M2`:

```
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 2 0
0 0 2 2 0
0 0 2 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
1 1 0 0 0
```

In other words, let `TICK()` and `ROTATE()` be the transformations above, we have

```
M1 = TICK(M0)
M2 = ROTATE(M1)
```

Note that I want to apply the transformation to the **entire** matrix. I **don't** want to keep track of the piece in code then apply transformation to the piece only.

What is the mathematical way to find the matrix transformation `TICK()` and `ROTATE()`? What mathematical concepts should I look into?

---

My findings so far:

1. `TICK()` and `ROTATE()` are not linear transformations, therefore there is no standard matrix A such that `A*M0 => M1`
2. The current matrix `M` is not expressive enough. We'd better transform it to something like [adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix).

---

Context: I'm building a 2D game and it will be awesome if my entire game can be expressed as matrix manipulations!

Comment: Considering you must treat a cell with a $1$ in a given position differently depending on if it's in the current piece or not, I sincerely doubt such a transformation will exist without an indication of which cells represent the current piece

Comment: Collision detection is going to be a problem. Also, say you have a column with a zero on top and all ones below it. How do we know those parts aren't supposed to move with the piece? There needs to be some means by which to isolate the piece from the rest of the matrix.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense, let me change the piece to `2` so that we know which is which.

Comment: In principle you could make a matrix that's twice the size of the playing board so that one half has the piece rotating/falling while the other half are the pieces that are stuck at the bottom. These would be overlaid to give the game's screen. Then it's possible to define rotate and tick like you describe as a linear transformation since each state of the board is a basis vector. This would be a very painful way of implementing collision detection since an $m\times n$ board would have $4^{m \times n}$ basis vectors.